# Upgrade Microsoft BotFramework 3.0 to 3.5

Tags: botframework

I have just upgraded my botframework from 3.0 to 3.5. it made changes into packages.config file and web.config file. 
I build the visual studio solution and it's building. 
but when I start the bot emulator it and send a message Hi, it gives me a error " Response status code does not indicate success: 400" and emulator displayed this message "Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[File of type 'text/plain']" see below image.

[image: See this image]
My question is it require to upgrade the bot connector (at azure side) also after upgrading the bot framework.
I am not sure what is the problem here. please suggests

Comment: Without seeing your code will be extremely hard to know what's going on. It seems an issue in the code.

Comment: It appears your bot is throwing an exception, and that text is getting returned to the emulator in a reply message. Can you catch the exception on the bot side where it is thrown?

Comment: Ok. I got this is not an issue related to framework. unfortunately it was Luis Api service which was down by Microsoft.  now it is working. need to close this thread.

Comment: Ok, good to know that was related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693941/luis-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added. You can delete this question if you want