# LUIS : An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am building bot with LUIS. 
Before 2 hours everything was ok.
My last publish on azure is from yesterday.
When i train and update my published application and then write a test query i am getting : An item with the same key has already been added.
Some help ?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue on all of my LUIS services, even the ones I haven't edited in a while. So my guess is that there is a problem at their end. Maybe give it a few hours then try again.

Comment: I hope they will fix asap :)

Comment: same issue here, hope they fix it is asap

Comment: same issue here

Comment: Works now ! Check your applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that starting today, the endpoints will be changing.

Try updating your LUIS endpoint hostname from **api.projectoxford.ai** to **westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com**.

See the image below for the notice and more instructions.

[image: LUIS Endpoint Update]

More info [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2051) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2052).