# LUIS Errors after making HTTP Query

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

Since this morning, I have been encountering different errors when making queries via the HTTP interface in LUIS, such as

```
{ "statusCode": 500, "message": "Internal server error", "activityId": "01c807b8-af77-487c-8b59-cc52fde15dfa" }
```

or

```
An item with the same key has already been added.
```

Occasionally, a valid JSON is returned. This LUIS application is the only one in my account. I have tried creating a new endpoint key in Azure and adding it to my LUIS application without success. The errors are also shown in the monitoring of my LUIS subscription in Azure.

Does anybody know if this is an error produced on the LUIS side, or if I have set up my LUIS application incorrectly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LUIS : An item with the same key has already been added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693941/luis-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An item with the same key has already been added.

Updated Post on luis.ai
[image]

Problem is on their End.But,now its working.

Comment: Ok thanks! May I ask where you saw this announcement such that next time I know if there is an outage or not?